# Disabled checkbox color

Tags: android, android-styles, android-checkbox

I have a button that enables/disables a checkbox but I cannot see the disabled checkbox due to the color it turns (my style background color must be the same color as the disabled checkbox). How do I change the color of a disabled checkbox and also ensure that the color returns to an "enabled" color when the checkbox becomes enabled again?

This is what I mean:

[image]

The checkbox in question is simple:

```
   <CheckBox
       android:id="@+id/settings_hide_nsfw_thumbnails"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: bro can u solve my little bit problem my question link [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62807993/i-can-successfully-download-image-in-my-phone-storage-but-not-showing-in-gallery)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest to define a new style and apply it to the checkbox in xml.

```
<style name="MyCheckBox" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/notactive</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/active</item>
</style>
```

apply it with `android:theme="@style/MyCheckBox"`

normal= not selected

Comment: Yep this was it. Thanks!

Comment: There is still alpha applied.